# How to show a shape or graphic in java with no window frame?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm having a hard time trying to make a Java program with just a shape (e.g rectangle) as main window. I don't want the shape to be inside the 'OS-window' (with buttons to close and minimize etc..)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722827/how-can-i-create-a-java-swing-app-that-covers-the-windows-title-bar

Comment: @erickson: That one was about full-screen mode. I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: It is a different application, but the solution is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can draw directly on the screen in Java (I tend to think you can't). But you could create a [`JDialog`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) (which doesn't appear in the taskbar) and call [`setUndecorated(true)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setUndecorated(boolean)) on it (to get rid of the title bar). Then you can do whatever custom painting you want with it.

**Edit:** [kts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71859/kts) points out that [`JWindow`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) will work even better for this purpose. From the Javadocs:

> It does not have the title bar, window-management buttons, or other trimmings associated with a `JFrame`, but it is still a "first-class citizen" of the user's desktop, and can exist anywhere on it.

And there's even a [no-argument constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html#JWindow()), so you don't have to worry about passing in a `null` owner!

Comment: you could just create a JWindow. It doesn't have that pesky JFrame/JDialog constructor. It doesn't show up in the task bar either. I don't hink it has decorations either. JDialog should work, but I always woory about passing null in as an argument.

Comment: Good tip on JWindow. I didn't even realize that class existed, but it seems perfect for this job.

Answer (score 1):

For more exotic shapes: [translucent and shaped windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/). Works only in 6u10 and later.