# Change the active application on OS X with Java and SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swt

Here is my specific scenario:

I have my application running in the background and I want to open a new window from my applications toolbar icon right click menu. For simplicity I am using a `MessageDialog`, and using the method `open()` on the dialog, the window should display and make itself the active window.

For some reason I've run into the problem that if I had some other application open and I try to open this new dialog, it opens, but behind the active application. The new dialog will open in front of the other windows of the same application, but not the other(active) application.

Is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: @user2494817 Question is about SWT, not AWT/Swing...

Comment: @Baz Right... this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722911/java-swt-application-bring-to-front    :)

Comment: @user2494817 This solution is specifically for windows, the question is for Mac OS X specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. Essentially you need to find your active workbench shell(the application shell) and use the following methods on that shell, followed by pushing the actual desired window to the front.

You could easily modify this to make your window appear maximized as well by adding the method `shell.setMaximized(true)` before the redraw.

```
private static void bringupDialog(WindowState state) {
   final Shell workbenchShell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();

   //bring up the application to front
   workbenchShell.setVisible( true );
   workbenchShell.setMinimized( false );
   workbenchShell.redraw();

   //focus on dialog
   workbenchShell.setActive();
   workbenchShell.forceActive();
   workbenchShell.setFocus();
   workbenchShell.forceFocus();
   workbenchShell.moveAbove( null );
   workbenchShell.redraw();

   Shell shell = instance.getShell(); // desired window shell
   shell.setActive();
   shell.forceActive();
   shell.setFocus();
   shell.forceFocus();
   shell.moveAbove( null );

   shell.redraw();
}
```